# sensor_msgs/JointState in cpp

Tags: ros, roscpp, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try set sensor_msgs/JointState and publish it

```
ros::Publisher joint_msg_pub = node.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("leg_joints_states", 1);
sensor_msgs::JointState joint_msg;
joint_msg.name[0] = "coxa_joint_r1";
joint_msg.position[0] = q_out(0);
joint_msg_pub.publish(joint_msg);
```

But when I launch node I get segmentation fault.
I incorrectly set the value in the message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125096/sensor_msgs/jointstate-in-cpp/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. This code example won't compile.
2. You are setting the first elements of the vectors, but there are 0 elements in a new message that you create. Use `.push_back` instead of setting the values to add new values.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2014-01-31**:\

1. Yes, I cut a lot of code :)
2. Thank you! .push_back is solution of the problem

**Comment by [ghanta1996](https://answers.ros.org/users/29905/ghanta1996/) on 2017-04-02**:
could you post the corrected code. please